# jQuery 1.6 prop() on div's title

Tags: jquery, attr, prop

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

What is the differnece between doing

```
$('div').prop('title','whatever'); //set
$('div').prop('title'); //get
```

and

```
$('div').attr('title','whatever'); //set
$('div').attr('title'); //get
```

`prop()` seems to behave the same as `attr()` in the case of div attribute. I read the 1.6 documentation for this but i'm still a little confused.

**THIS IS NOT EXACT DUPLICATE OF** [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr). This post doesn't answer the question. Please do not close it.

Comment: @Frédéric That's already been closed itself...

Comment: @Pinkie, your previous question was closed because it already was a duplicate. Posting the same question again is probably not the way to go. If the answers to the original question do not suit you, please expand your question to clarify exactly you're missing.

Comment: @Frédéric Hmm, I didn't notice the user was the same. All the same, it's a valid question, and avowedly not a duplicate of `prop` vs `attr`.  The first question should not have been closed.

Comment: @Frédéric There is not duplicate to this question. Otherwise i woudln't whave asked it. You should pay more attention before voting to close.

Comment: @lonesomeday, @Pinkie, since `title` is both an HTML attribute and a DOM property, it makes sense for `prop()` to behave as `attr()` in that context. Answers to the original question already make that clear, so I fail to see why this isn't a dupe...

Comment: @Frédéric "title is both an HTML attribute and a DOM property"  wouldn't been an excellent answer just as @lonesomeda pointed in this answer.

Comment: @Pinkie, duly noted, but I really thought the answers to the original question made that obvious. My bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`prop` and `attr` do not always give different results.  They only give different results when there is a difference between a property and an attribute.

For instance, with the `checked` attribute/property:

```
$(':checkbox').prop('checked'); // returns boolean true false
$(':checkbox').attr('checked'); // returns string "checked" or undefined
```

This is all well explained on [`prop` vs `attr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

However, with the `title` attribute/property, there is no difference.  They are both strings, and setting one will set the other to that value.